# How can I get the uncompressed size of gzip file without actually decompressing it?

Tags: unix, shell, gzip, gz

Please find my OS details:

```
$ uname -a
AIX xxyy 1 6 000145364C00
```

I've tried the following command to get size of a file in gzip archive:

```
$ gzip -l mycontent.DAT.Gz
compressed  uncompr.   ratio   uncompressed_name
-1223644243 1751372002 -75.3%  mycontent.DAT.Gz
```

Not sure how to interpret the unzipped size from this.  Compressed file size close to 4 GB.

So, I tried this option in order to capture correct data:

```
$ zcat mycontent.DAT.Gz | wc -c
```

It gives me this error:

```
mycontent.DAT.Gz.Z:A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
0
```

Can you please tell me how to capture this value from shell script without decompressing the source file?

Comment: Are you sure about the integrity of the archive? It reports its own compressed size as ~1.7G. If it is really ~4GB I would guess there is a problem.

Answer (score 53):

To answer the question title:

> How can I get the uncompressed size of gzip file without actually decompressing it?

As you obviously know, the option `-l` (`--list`) is usually showing the uncompressed size.
What it shows is not calculated from the data, but was stored in the header as part of the compressed file.

In your case, the `-l` option does not work for some reason.
But it's not possible to 'measure' the uncompressed size from the raw compressed data - there is just no information about anything else in the compressed data - which is not surprising, as the point of compression is to leave out anything not needed.

You do not need to store the uncompressed data on the disk: `zcat file.gz | wc -c` is the right approach - but as @OleTange answered, your `zcat` seems to be not the one from `gzip`.
The alternative is using the `gzip` options `-d` (`--decompress`)  and `-c` (`--to-stdout`), combined with `wc` option `-c` (`--bytes`):

```
gzip -dc file.gz | wc -c
```

Comment: The `-l` option has a bug for files bigger than 4GB: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=149775

Answer (score 12):

I like using `pv` as it shows a more human readable information and progress:

```
zcat file.gz | pv > /dev/null
```

Outputs:

```
7,65GiB 0:00:44 [ 174MiB/s] [
```

Comment: this also decompresses the source file like [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/619659/241386) so it's not a solution to this problem

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the question. It seems he doesn't want to generate a decompressed file as he complains only about the error he is getting from `wc`. There is no way of getting the size without reading the contents. @phuclv

Comment: No, decompressing the content is never necessary to get file metadata. The header **always** contains the original size of each file and their hashes to compare after decrypting

Comment: @phuclv no. Headers give incorrect information many times. I came here because of this. My 1.7GB file was showing 4GB decompressed when actually it was almost 8GB. Check this issue: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=149775#10

Answer (score 10):

Your `zcat` is not GNU zcat but from compress. Try:

```
gzcat mycontent.DAT.Gz | LC_ALL=C wc -c
gzip -dc mycontent.DAT.Gz | LC_ALL=C wc -c
```

Comment: This decompresses the source file. Maybe it's what the OP wants, but this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Ah, that explains why it was looking for a file ending in .Z

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the only way to know is to extract it and count the bytes. gzip files do not properly report uncompressed data >4GB in size. See [RFC1952](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1952), which defines the gzip file format:

```
ISIZE (Input SIZE)
    This contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input
    data modulo 2^32.
```

This discrepancy might be a little more obvious if whatever version of gzip you are using didn't have a bug: it is treating the `ISIZE` value as a signed 32-bit integer (resulting in -1223644243), rather than an unsigned 32-bit integer (which would result in 3071323053).

The most you can determine based on the header alone is that the real size of the uncompressed data is

```
(n * 4,294,967,296) + 3,071,323,053
```

where `n` is some whole number.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(n * 4,294,967,296) + 3,071,323,053`?

Comment: @Eric Whoops, you're right! Edited to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

`gzip -l` did not work for me, just `git -1` ... but this did:

```
unzip -l file.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding everything sites in the web, and don't resolve this problem the get size when file size is  bigger of 4GB.

**my solution is this**:

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ timeout --signal=SIGINT 1s tar -tvf oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz
    -rw-r--r-- oracle/oinstall 111828 2018-03-03 03:05 oracle.20180303.030001.log
    -rw-r----- oracle/oinstall 6666911744 2018-03-03 03:05 oracle.20180303.030001.dmp
```

for get total size from gz file:

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ echo $(timeout --signal=SIGINT 1s tar -tvf oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz | awk '{print $3}') | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
    6667023572
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained that it only works for tarballs and you cleaned it up (timeout is not necessary, and neither is grep).